# A circle with parametric shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, pst-func

How can I produce a circle with parametric color shading, such as in the following example? The parameter here is the angle $-\pi \le \theta \pi$ which varies through the rainbow colors.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small cheat with TikZ's library `shading`. I don't know how to rotate rainbow's colors.

[image]

```
% with Nguyen Quang Dung
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % decorations
\def\a{1.1} \def\b{.03}
\draw[gray,nodes={black,scale=.5}]
(0,-\a) node[below]{$0$} node[below=4mm]{$x$}
(1,-1-\b)--(1,-\a) node[below]{$1$}
(-1,-1-\b)--(-1,-\a) node[below]{$-1$}
(-\a,0) node[left]{$0$} node[left=4mm]{$y$}
(-1-\b,1)--(-\a,1) node[left]{$1$}
(-1-\b,-1)--(-\a,-1) node[left]{$-1$};
\draw 
(-\a,0)--(\a,0) (0,\a)--(0,-\a)
(-\a,-\a) rectangle(\a,\a);

% now shading
\shade[shading=color wheel,even odd rule]
(0,0) circle (1)
(0,0) circle (.98);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```